# I can't upload and update user profile image using laravel10, inertia.js and vue.js 3

Tags: laravel, image, forms, vue.js, inertiajs

By submitting the form in Edit.vue / EditAvatar.vue, the new image doesn't appear in the Laravel UserController (i write dd(request()); and request() atributes and other routes where image data cound potentially be is empty) update function because of reasons I dont't understand, and I can't validate and update the new profile image.

Edit.vue

```
    <Layout>
        <div id="main-div">
            <h1 class="text-center">Change Your Data</h1>
            <EditName :user="user"/>
            <EditPhoneNumber :user="user"/>
            <EditEmail :user="user"/>
            <EditAvatar :user="user"/>
        </div>
    </Layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from "../../Layout/App.vue";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import EditName from "./Edit/EditName.vue";
import EditEmail from "./Edit/EditEmail.vue";
import EditPhoneNumber from "./Edit/EditPhoneNumber.vue";
import EditAvatar from "./Edit/EditAvatar.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        Layout,
        EditName,
        EditEmail,
        EditPhoneNumber,
        EditAvatar,
        Link,
    },
    props: {
        errors: Object,
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#main-div {
    margin-top: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 140px;
}
</style>
```

EditAvatar.vue view

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mx-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <form
                enctype="multipart/form-data"
                class="form mt-5"
                @submit.prevent="submitAvatar"
            >
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label for="avatar" class="text-dark">Profile Image:</label
                    ><br />
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="avatar"
                        id="avatar"
                        class="form-control border-primary"
                        @input="form.avatar = $event.target.files[0]"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center my-3">
                    <div class="form-group ms-3">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-warning text-primary py-2 px-3"
                        >
                            Save Profile Image
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const props = defineProps({
    user: Object,
});

const form = useForm({
    avatar: null,
});

function submitAvatar() {
    // console.log("Avatar data:", form.avatar);
    router.put(`/profile/${props.user.id}/edit`, {
        _method: 'put',
        avatar: form.avatar,
    });
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

UserController edit function

````
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user['avatar'] = asset('storage/' . $user->avatar);

        return Inertia::render("User/Edit")->with('user', $user);
    }     ```

UserController update function

```     public function update(){
        $id = auth()->user()->id;

        dd(request());

        $user = User::find($id);
        $validated = [];

        if (request()->has('name')) {
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'name' => 'required|min:3|max:40',
            ]);
        }

        if (request()->has('phone_number')) {
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'phone_number' => 'required|min:8|max:20',
            ]);
        } 

        if (request()->has('email')) {
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            ]);
        }

        if (request()->has('avatar')) {
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'avatar' => 'required|image',
            ]);

            $avatarPath = request()->file('avatar')->store('profile', 'public');
            $validated['avatar'] = $avatarPath;

            if($user->avatar) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($user->avatar);
            }
        };

        if (request()->has('password') && Hash::check(request()->old_password, $user->password)) {
            request()->validate([
                'old_password' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required|min:3|confirmed',
            ]);

            $user->update([
                'password' => Hash::make(request()->password),
            ]);

            return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Password updated successfully');
        }

        $user->update($validated);

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'Profile updated successfully!');
    }     ```

In the code above, I've written what I had already tried. In my opinion, the problem lies in the EditAvatar.vue component because I can't receive the image in the update function. However, when I console log the image data after submitting the form, it works, and I can see all the data about the image I uploaded a few seconds ago.
````

Comment: You cannot put images - you must post images.

Answer (score 0):

try using `router.post` instead of `router.put`

Comment: Can you offer additional detail on why you think this would be useful here?

Comment: in inertiajs it is the right way to submit files if you refer to the documentation https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads#file-upload-example under Multipart limitations